# Ember: TypeError: internalModel.getRecord is not a function

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm inside a component, trying to add a newly created entity in an action:

```
var stakeholding = this.get('store').createRecord('stakeholding', {[...]});

var allCarings = this.get('allCarings');
allCarings.insertAt(0, stakeholding);
```

But I get this error message:

```
TypeError: internalModel.getRecord is not a function
```

`allCarings` is initialized at page launch like this, inside the component:

```
this.store.find('stakeholding', {[...]}).then(function(data){   
    _this.set('allCarings', data);
});
```

How should I add my entity to the array properly?

Comment: If you remove `allCarings.insertAt(0, stakeholding);` you don't get that error? What's server response for `this.store.find('stakeholding', {[...]})`?

Answer (score 0):

You should add record to `allCarings` array using `pushObject`:

```
var stakeholding = this.get('store').createRecord('stakeholding', {[...]});

var allCarings = this.get('allCarings');
allCarings.pushObject(stakeholding);
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm new to Ember and don't know exactly why but that's what worked for me:

`allCarings.insertAt(0, stakeholding._internalModel);`